# How to read lines from file into array?

Tags: ruby

This is what I want to do, but with a one-liner:

```
lines = Array.new
File.open('test.txt').each { |line| lines << line }
```

Possible?

Comment: Be *VERY* careful reading a file into memory all at once. It's not scalable, and can easily make a program crawl if the file turns out to be bigger than the available memory. Line-by-line is as fast and is the way to go if at all possible.

Comment: @theTinMan `IO::foreach` does file processing _line by line_. But when someone is trying to get the lines in an _array_, `#readlines` very good way to go, rather than `ar = []; File.foreach('test.txt') { |line| ar << line }`. I didn't check, but I am sure, in `C` level, `readlines()` probably does something like that internally already.As opposed to slurping up the whole file at once and *then* breaking it down into lines.

Comment: `each` is safe because it's the instance version of `foreach`. I have read the C source, and `readlines` doesn't scale because it aggregates an entire file into memory. That's a bad practice, even today when machines have more memory and are faster, because files are bigger too. An unexpectedly big file, bigger than Ruby can handle, will take a machine to a crawl. That's unnecessary, and unacceptable in production environments.

Comment: See "[Why is slurping a file bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad?)"

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Do as below :

```
File.readlines('test.txt')
```

Read [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> ri IO::readlines

= IO::readlines

(from ruby site)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  IO.readlines(name, sep=$/ [, open_args])     -> array
  IO.readlines(name, limit [, open_args])      -> array
  IO.readlines(name, sep, limit [, open_args]) -> array

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Reads the entire file specified by name as individual lines, and
returns those lines in an array. Lines are separated by sep.

  a = IO.readlines("testfile")
  a[0]   #=> "This is line one\n"

If the last argument is a hash, it's the keyword argument to open. See IO.read
for detail.
```

**Example**

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> cat out.txt
name,age,location
Ram,12, UK
Jadu,11, USA
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> ruby -e "p File::readlines('./out.txt')"
["name,age,location\n", "Ram,12, UK\n", "Jadu,11, USA\n"]
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```

Comment: How can't you love Ruby :)

Comment: @sandre89 what do you mean? :)

Comment: I meant that this is just one more example of such a brilliant and well designed language. You want to "read lines" from a "file" into an array, and Ruby's answer is `File.readlines(filename)`. :)

Comment: if your input file has a BOM you may have to specify the encoding such as `File.readlines(filename, encoding: 'bom|utf-8')`

Answer (score 2):

I use the same `File.readlines` methods as explained in the accepted answer.

However when I read in strings from a text file, I typically want to get rid of the newline characters at the end of each line.

Therefore I use this:

```
 File.readlines('adopters.txt').map(&:chomp)
```